# What is wrong with this raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm using the same raycast in the code for picking up and dropping. When i have the item at the cursor, at the first time he hits the square under it. When i pick it again and want to drop it on the same place he hits only the item and not the square under it. I don't get this, as the item has the same position at the cursor both times.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
   RaycastHit hit;
   if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
      Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Diamond(Clone)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
ColorLogic:checkMouseClick () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:97)
ColorLogic:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:30)

Square_3_10
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
ColorLogic:checkMouseClick () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:97)
ColorLogic:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:30)

Diamond(Clone)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
ColorLogic:checkMouseClick () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:97)
ColorLogic:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:30)

Diamond(Clone)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
ColorLogic:checkMouseClick () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:97)
ColorLogic:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ColorLogic.cs:30)
```

See Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S8iF3gYcMDmo1WwZlb1H21d-n8cTn2R-/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the behaviour is due to the fact that the ray hits **all collider on the scene** and puts the first hit info into the **RaycastHit**.

There are several ways to accomplish this.

1. Use a layer mask
2. Disable the collider when the diamond is dropped (but you'd like to drag and drop again, don't you?

[The first one is the best so](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) define a LayerMask and process it into your logic after the diamond is dropped.

```
int squareMask = 10;
int maxDistance = 100;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, squareMask)) {
    // process here
}
```

Comment: But when i drop it first time why does the ray then hit the grid under it and not the diamond? I understand what you mean, but the behaviour is an other.

Comment: I'm not sure, that would depend on the process queue from the `Raycast`. But I think it may be due to the fact that the diamond game object is closer to the raycast source point than the square. Does the **square** and **diamond** colliders overlap each to the point that have the same surface when the ray hits?